# How to avoid sub folders in snowflake copy statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a requirement to exclude certain folder from prefix and process the data in snowflake (Copy statement)

In the below example I need to process files under emp/ and exclude files from abc/

Input :

s3://bucket1/emp/

```
E1.CSV
E2.CSV
/abc/E11.csv
```

s3://bucket1/emp/abc/ - E11.csv

Output :

s3://bucket1/emp/

```
E1.CSV
E2.CSV
```

Is there any suggestion around pattern to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

With the `pattern` keyword you can *try* to exclude certain files.  However when using the pattern matching with the NOT syntax, you exclude any file with ***any*** of the characters.

Assuming your stage URL is defined as `s3://bucket1/emp/`

```
LS @MY_STAGE pattern = '[^abc].*';
```

- Excludes anything starting with a, b, or c

```
LS @MY_STAGE pattern = '[^a][^b][^c][^\\/].*';
```

- Excludes anything where:

  - The first character is a, OR
  - The second character is b, OR
  - The third character is c, OR
  - The fourth character is a forward slash /

### Edit

After testing with Sharvan's example. Here is what I've found:

**Doesn't work:**
`ls @my_stage PATTERN='^((?!/abc/).)*$';` because the first forward slash is duplicated as part of the stage URL (it is automatically appended to the stage URL if not present)

**Works:** `ls @my_stage PATTERN='^((?!abc/).)*$';` because the first forward slash is removed

> Updated as the forward slash does not need to be escaped

Snowflake does not support backreferences (per their documentation) but there is no mention of lookaheads or lookbehinds, which I thought was un-supported.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#backreferences

Comment: Your comment on the starting `/` for a top level folder is correct, but `/` works fine for me unescaped.  So I use `top/` or `/sub/` (tested with AWS S3).

Comment: Hi Chris  your first statement about   "Doesn't work: "  I tested this  without unescaped it is working.

Comment: I stand corrected, there is no need to escape the forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to exclude the prefix pattern

```
ls @stage PATTERN='^((?!/abc/).)*$'
```

Comment: Nice, always imagined lookbehind and -ahead was unsupported.